# xdebug profiler laravel 5.5 windows empty grindfile

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug-profiler

I am trying to profile Laravel 5.5 app on Windows 8.1 machine with xdebug 2.5.5 php version 7.0.0. php is running as cgi

Debugging works excellent i can debug but the profiler files are filled with this Laravel error (this is only with Laravel app, in simple php file profiling works fine):

```
version: 1 creator: xdebug 2.5.5 (PHP 7.0.15-dev)
cmd: D:\www\laravel55\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time

fl=(1)
fn=(2770) php::error_get_last
122 0

fl=(1)
fn=(74)
122 0

fl=(88)
fn=(2771) Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown
120 73
cfl=(1)
cfn=(2770)
calls=1 0 0
122 0
cfl=(1)
cfn=(74)
calls=1 0 0
122 0
```

I have tried with xdebug 2.5.5 php version 7.1.9. same thing.

This are xdebug settings:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="D:\AppServ\xdebug\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
;xdebug.remote_port="<the port for Xdebug to listen to>" (the default port is 9000)
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\AppServ\xdebug\tmp"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

Answer (score 4):

The grid file is probably empty because it is overwritten several times in the same request.

You can add the timestamp + script location into the filename to prevent this:

```
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
```